# How do I make sure OUTPUT INSERTED is in correct order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this `@TempTable` with only 2 columns `ProductName` and `TempID`:

```
ProductName | TempID  
------------+------
GTX 1080    | NULL
GTX 1080Ti  | NULL
RX 580      | NULL
```

I will insert this to `TblProduct` (2 columns: `ProductName` and `ID`) with the following command:

```
INSERT INTO TblProduct (ProductName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @Test123(ID)
    SELECT ProductName 
    FROM @TempTable
```

Is it guaranteed that the output result in `@Test123` is in correct order? Meaning that if the result is 1, 2, and 3.

- 1 should refer to GTX 1080
- 2 should refer to GTX 1080Ti
- 3 should refer to RX 580

Is it possible to update `TempID` in `@TempTable` from `ID` in `@Test123`? If yes, how? I was thinking of something like `UPDATE ... SELECT ...`

Comment: Tables have no order, so question 1 is moot.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: What if I do `SELECT ProductName FROM @TempTable ORDER BY ProductName` when inserting. Will I then be able to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed at all.
Tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature - in other words - the records have no inherent order.

However, you can output more than one column using the output clause, so for your sample data, you could output both `ProductName` and `ID` (of course, this means that the table variable `@Test123` must have (at least) these two columns):

```
INSERT INTO TblProduct (ProductName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.ProductName INTO @Test123(ID, ProductName)
SELECT ProductName 
FROM @TempTable
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/JYO57438)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the rows to appear in alphabetical order, as in your example then say:

```
select ProductName
from TblProduct
order by ProductName;
```

If you want some other order then you need a column that defines that order so that you can put the appropriate order on the select statement.  For example, if you want to get the rows back in the order you inserted them, define your table as:

```
create table TblProduct
(
    id             int identity(1,1) not null,
    ProductName    varchar(20),
    tempID         int
);
```

then

```
select ProductName
from TblProduct
order by id;
```